# Java | what is the difference between peek() and lastElement() method in Stack

Tags: java, stack

Java |
what is the difference between peek() and lastElement() method in Stack.
They both can return the element of top of stack, is there have performance difference or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between these two methods is the class of the exception that gets thrown in the case where the stack is empty.  Use whichever one you prefer.  The standard implementations in JDK 8 are more-or-less identical, so there will be no measurable performance difference.

Possibly the reason why `Stack` provides a second version of the same method is that the words `peek`, `pop` and `push` are traditionally associated with programming a stack.

From **java/util/Stack.java**

```
 public synchronized E peek() {
    int len = size();

    if (len == 0)
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    return elementAt(len - 1);
}
```

and from **java/util/Vector.java**

```
 public synchronized E lastElement() {
    if (elementCount == 0) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    return elementData(elementCount - 1);
}
```